# Different charset between mysql and web

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with string from my database mysql.
I have a form with some input text and text area.
I have a list of product with the button "Update". If I click this button the new page is so done:

```
<form action="modify.php">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name_from_db; ?>">
<br>
<input type="text" name="desc" value="<?php echo $desc_from_db; ?>">
<br/>
...
</form>
```

The problem are the lecters like "è", "à", ecc. In database arrive directely with that value and not with `"&egrave;"`. But now in input form their value isn't correct.

I try to do this:

```
$desc_from_db= str_replace("è", "&egrave;", $desc_from_db);
```

Probably the charset (`latin1_swedish_ci`) it's different. 
What do I have to do?

**EDIT**
I tried to do a solution and it seems work correctely. It isn't the best solution. Can you judge it? Could have some bug?
The lecters dangerous are only 6: "à", "è", "ì", "ò", "ù", "é".
So with the function: ord ($lecter) I notest that "è" have the code 232.
So I could do (checking all the lecter of the word):

```
if(ord($lecter) == 232)
$word = substring($word, 0, $index)."&egrave;".substring($word, $index+1, strlen($word);
```

Comment: I think you need to read up on [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: yeah you need to set your database to UTF8-general-ci and also set your headers to UTF-8

Comment: Yes, Otherwise whenever update or insert query before using below line: mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); after you write your code.

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani I have set it but the situation does not change

Comment: you are making a mysql connection. i recommend using PDO or mysqli and then add this to the header. mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); mb_http_output('UTF-8'); mb_http_input('UTF-8'); mb_language('uni'); mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');

Comment: Don't use Latin1. We're in the 21st century now. (And have been for a decade and a half!)

Comment: I use it only because standard. If I use utf8-general-ci do I have to set utf8 as meta tag?